# Map center is not getting change when zoom the map in android

Tags: java, android

I am not getting center of map, I want to put markers on map run time,but when I try to zoom map it is not point to center, and markers are placed on same position how I refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but I recommend you read through this

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html